# store current_user (devise) in related table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use devise for our user management.

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name

  has_many :carts   

end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
  belongs_to :user

end
```

cart_controller:

```
def create
    @cart = current_user.cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

private

    def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end
```

module:

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

    def set_cart 
      @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = @cart.id 
    end
end
```

When a cart is created (when a list item is added) i want to store in user.id in cart table (user_id).  So i thought to use the current_user method like this

```
  @cart = current_user.cart.new(cart_params)
```

The cart is created with the items but the user_id in the cart table remains empty. What am i doing wrong?

thanks..remco

Comment: current_user.cart.new(cart_params) should be  current_user.carts.new(cart_params)

Comment: Did you try Matt's answer? did it work?

Comment: yes...but did not work...i think is has todo with nested strong params?

Comment: See the answer, also do you have any sort of validation in `Cart` class? if so, can you post them too?

Comment: no i don't use validation in the cart model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt Gibson pointed out(and that's how I would do to create new cart from an association):

```
@cart = current_user.carts.build(cart_params)
```

But, I think it is not working as expect because of Rails 4's strong parameters. For that you might want to change this:

```
private

    def cart_params
      params[:cart]
    end
```

to:

```
private

    def cart_params
      params.require(:cart).permit(:name, :state) # at :name, :state use attributes which you're getting from the form for cart!
    end
```

Change

```
def set_cart 
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id 
end
```

to:

```
def set_cart 
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = current_user.carts.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id # since you're setting this ID in session which you use for update later!
end
```

Comment: i did this def cart_params
      params.require(:cart).permit(:id, :user_id) # at :name, :state use attributes which you're getting from the form for cart!
    end   but doesn't work

Comment: Alright, your issue seems like somewhere else, can you please tell what happens at `if @cart.save`? does it go in if or else?

Comment: maybe is has todo with the before_action :set_cart in the cart_controller? def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@cart = current_user.carts.build(cart_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@cart = current_user.carts.new(cart_params)
```

As it is `has_many` relation you have to use `carts` instead of cart

Comment: thanks..i tried that...but doesn't work. I thought it has todo with nested strong params?